# Keyword ending ccTLD domain names and SEO

Tags: seo, domains, top-level-domains

There is huge number of [ccTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain) top domain names that is available for registration.

This is country specific [domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains)  could be used for `keyword ending domain`. e.g `assemb.ly`, `architectu.re`, `stud.io`.... etc

I am just wondering how is SEO goes for that kind of domains?

The reason I am asking because the `.com` and `.net` domain names I want to register are not available so that is why currently I am researching the option of `keyword ending domain` but not sure if it is a good idea to use such kind of domain for global not country specific website.

**In my case I am looking to `.re` domain name.**

Or it is better to come up with different `.com` or `.net` domain name that is available instead of using `keyword ending domain` in case when `.com` or `.net` are not available?

What do you think?

UPDATE:
here is [article](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2266224/Google-Starts-Treating-More-Country-Code-Top-Level-Domains-as-Generic-TLDs) I came across but cant see `.re` domain in the list...

Would [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/62399) Google Webmaster Tools trick really help to set ccTLD to target global:

> Set a geographic target:
>
> On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want. Click the
>   gear icon , and then click Site Settings. In the Geographic target
>   section, select the option you want.

?

UPDATE: Found a good discussion [here](https://forums.digitalpoint.com/threads/io-vs-com-what-to-choose.2657402/) on that topic and this [article](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2286477/Matt-Cutts-Be-Careful-About-How-You-Choose-Your-ccTLDs)

Comment: I would personally avoid advice from DigitalPoint forums. The other links you referenced (SearchEngineWatch and Google itself) are more trustworthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer. There is no SEO effect to domain names such as `assemb.ly` other than what we already know. All the other information you pointed to refers to geo-location and finding sites with particular target geo-locations.

The reason why these tricks are used is because it is memorable and cute. It is a marketing ploy *de jour*. In fact, it can be misleading because the search engine results page (SERP) may apply geo-location tactics to the result.

If you are doing business in a particular country, then using a ccTLD makes sense. Before any of you scream bloody murder, using a ccTLD is fine for other reasons too. But there will be a geo-location factor that you will always have to contend with. If you are more global in nature, then I recommend  the traditional `.com`, `.net`, `.org`, etc. However, if you are say an Italian company and primarily sell within Italy and surrounding countries, then I would advise a ccTLD, e.g. `.it`.